# Use of send keyword in Ruby Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to Ruby, so I am having difficulty understanding the functionality of the code.

I have a class having a structure given below.

```
1. class MyClass::Container
2.   def self.call
3.     @containers || {}
4.   end
5. 
6.   def self.[] namespace
7.     @containers ||= Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = new }
8.     @containers[namespace]
9.   end
10. 
11.  def add_flag name
12.    self.class.attr_reader name
13.  end
```

Then I have another module having a structure given below.

```
1. module MyClass::MyFlag
2.   def self.enabled? flag, value = "true", identifier: nil
3.     if identifier
4.       MyClass::Container[namespace].send(name).value(identifier: identifier) == value
5.     else
6.      MyClass::Container[namespace].send(name).value == value
7.     end
8.   end
9. end
```

I am having a problem understanding how line no 4 & 6 are working in `MyClass::MyFlag`. I mean how the `.send` `.value` is working ?.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that is no longer maintained and has unpatched security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass::Container[namespace]
```

is an object.

```
.send(name)
```

sends the message in `name` to that object. E.g.

```
.send(:foo)
```

sends `:foo` to that object as if it were called like `obj.foo`. That expression returns another object.

```
.value
```

sends the message `:value` to the object returned by `.send(name)`, as if it were called like

```
.send(name).send(:value)
```

And that returns another object.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a method call language,  but using the combination of [respond_to?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) and [send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send) you can make it seem like a message passing language.

For example here is a simple method that will "send a message" to an object, if the message corresponds to a method that exists on the receiver object, the object will respond with the result of the method call.  However if the method does not exist, it will simply respond with a message indicating that the message is not understood, ie the receiver does not have a matching method"

```rb
def send_msg(receiver, msg)
  receiver.respond_to?(msg) ? "I understood that message and my reply is #{receiver.send(msg)}" : "I don't understand that message"
end
```

For example a string object has a method `size` but does not have a method `foo`,  so here are the results of sending these messages to a string `some_string`

```
send_msg("some_string", "size")
=> "I understood that message and my reply is 11"
```

but sending a message that does not correspond to a method returns the following;

```
send_msg("some_string", "foo")
=> "I don't understand that message"
```